# osdev - VGA in protected mode initializing weirdly

Tags: c, assembly, x86, osdev, vga

So, I have been trying to make a simple OS, that enters mode 13h (using my previously used code that should work on protected mode (it atleast did on my previous OS using grub as bootloader)
 The code is posted below.
 When i try to use this new code, i get really, really weird output. The writing pixel to the screen doesn't work, but the change in screen resolution does indicate that some video mode was initiated.. 
 The video mode seems to be around 640px on Y axis and about 1940pixels on X axis
 The asm code for initiating the c code is also below, in case that is the issue. 
ASM loader:

```
[org 0x7C00]
bits 16
_start:
    ;segment registers
    mov ax, 0x0000
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0x7C00
    mov ax, 0x07E0
    mov ds, ax
    
    ;enter protected mode
    cli
    lgdt [gdtr]
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 1 
    mov cr0, eax
    jmp main
gdt_start:
    dq 0x0000000000000000
    dq 0x00CF9A000000FFFF
    dq 0x00CF92000000FFFF
gdt_end:
gdtr:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1
    dd gdt_start
main:
    ;Segment reload 2
    mov ax, DATA_SEG
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov ss, ax
```

C program (simpliest possible example):

```
#include <stdint.h>
unsigned char g_320x200x256[] =
{
/* MISC */
    0x63,
/* SEQ */
    0x03, 0x01, 0x0F, 0x00, 0x0E,
/* CRTC */
    0x5F, 0x4F, 0x50, 0x82, 0x54, 0x80, 0xBF, 0x1F,
    0x00, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x9C, 0x0E, 0x8F, 0x28, 0x40, 0x96, 0xB9, 0xA3,
    0xFF,
/* GC */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x05, 0x0F,
    0xFF,
/* AC */
    0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
    0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F,
    0x41, 0x00, 0x0F, 0x00, 0x00
};
#define VGA_AC_INDEX        0x3C0
#define VGA_AC_WRITE        0x3C0
#define VGA_AC_READ         0x3C1
#define VGA_INSTAT_READ     0x3DA
#define VGA_MISC_WRITE      0x3C2
#define VGA_MISC_READ       0x3CC
#define VGA_ADDRESS 0xA0000
/*          COLOR emulation     MONO emulation */
#define VGA_CRTC_INDEX      0x3D4       /* 0x3B4 */
#define VGA_CRTC_DATA       0x3D5       /* 0x3B5 */
#define VGA_GC_INDEX        0x3CE
#define VGA_GC_DATA         0x3CF
#define VGA_SEQ_INDEX       0x3C4
#define VGA_SEQ_DATA        0x3C5

#define VGA_NUM_AC_REGS     21
#define VGA_NUM_CRTC_REGS   25
#define VGA_NUM_GC_REGS     9
#define VGA_NUM_SEQ_REGS    5

uint8_t inb(uint16_t port) {
    uint8_t value;
    asm volatile ("inb %1, %0" : "=a"(value) : "Nd"(port));
    return value;
}
void outb(uint16_t port, uint8_t value) {
    asm volatile ("outb %0, %1" : : "a"(value), "Nd"(port));
}
int main(){
    unsigned char* regs = g_320x200x256;
    unsigned i;

   ; vga mode driver (originally from osdev wiki)

/* write MISCELLANEOUS reg */
    outb(VGA_MISC_WRITE, *regs);
    regs++;
/* write SEQUENCER regs */
    for(i = 0; i < VGA_NUM_SEQ_REGS; i++)
    {
        outb(VGA_SEQ_INDEX, i);
        outb(VGA_SEQ_DATA, *regs);
        regs++;
    }
/* unlock CRTC registers */
    outb(VGA_CRTC_INDEX, 0x03);
    outb(VGA_CRTC_DATA, inb(VGA_CRTC_DATA) | 0x80);
    outb(VGA_CRTC_INDEX, 0x11);
    outb(VGA_CRTC_DATA, inb(VGA_CRTC_DATA) & ~0x80);
/* make sure they remain unlocked */
    regs[0x03] |= 0x80;
    regs[0x11] &= ~0x80;
/* write CRTC regs */
    for(i = 0; i < VGA_NUM_CRTC_REGS; i++)
    {
        outb(VGA_CRTC_INDEX, i);
        outb(VGA_CRTC_DATA, *regs);
        regs++;
    }
/* write GRAPHICS CONTROLLER regs */
    for(i = 0; i < VGA_NUM_GC_REGS; i++)
    {
        outb(VGA_GC_INDEX, i);
        outb(VGA_GC_DATA, *regs);
        regs++;
    }
/* write ATTRIBUTE CONTROLLER regs */
    for(i = 0; i < VGA_NUM_AC_REGS; i++)
    {
        (void)inb(VGA_INSTAT_READ);
        outb(VGA_AC_INDEX, i);
        outb(VGA_AC_WRITE, *regs);
        regs++;
    }
/* lock 16-color palette and unblank display */
    (void)inb(VGA_INSTAT_READ);
    outb(VGA_AC_INDEX, 0x20);
    unsigned char *VGA = (unsigned char*) VGA_ADDRESS;
    VGA[0] = 0;
    VGA[1] = 1;
    VGA[2] = 2;
    ;Infinite loop at end
    while(1);
}
```

For now, i am copying the compiled binary code after the asm bootloader and 0x55AA at the 511'th and 512'th byte

Steps to reproduce:
`nasm -f bin kernel.asm` Compiles the bootloader
`i686-elf-gcc -nostdlib -ffreestanding -O2 -Wall -Wextra -m32 -c vgacode.c -o kern_c.o` Compiles the c file (i386-gcc should work as well) 
`objcopy -O binary kern_c.o kernel.o`  Convert from elf32 to bin
Then, you can copy the code using cat (`cat kenrnel kernel.o > file2.bin`) , and emulate using:
`qemu-system-x86_64 -fda file2.bin`

I have tried to recheck the code, use qemu in various modes, exporting memory, etc.

Comment: You don't seem to set up segment registers at all. Also just sticking `main:` at the end of the asm and expecting the C `main` to be there is asking for trouble. Your question isn't clear either, what do you mean "real mode" when this code is clearly trying to switch to protected mode? How does `grub` even come into play?

Comment: Well, the files are catted behind eachother and since the C code is compiled as binary file, the main function is starting at the first byte. Its the same way like if i was loading from the disk, except instead of the c code being in second sector it is behind the first sector. By the way the protected mode works, when i dont do while(1); at the end it it gets into boot loop. grub matters because it works if the same code is running trough grub

Comment: Boot loop means nothing, without setting up segments your code is doing who knows what. The `main` is not guaranteed to start at the first byte, especially since you do have two other functions not even marked `static` which might not be optimized away. As I said, asking for trouble, even if it happens to work. Unclear how you ran this via grub, but if you used multiboot that works because grub then does set up the segments properly and jumps to the proper entry point. Without reloading `cs` and `ds` you are likely just fetching random data and dumping those into the registers.

Comment: Well when i do while(1); at the start of main, the code starts with EB FE (equal to jmp $ in asm)

Comment: That is just luck. Might not have anything to do with your current problem but keep in mind for future reference.

Comment: Ok, so i added the segment init, and the resolution seems to be right.. sorry

Comment: FYI, on my system even the data section gets placed before the code and I do get the `inb`/`outb` before `main` as well.

Comment: Hmmm, thats weird

Comment: I have moved the functions differently, but the pixels are still not showing up for some reason

Comment: You should reload the segments after you switch to protected mode (including a far jump for `cs`). Also the way you just copy from an unlinked object, the addresses will probably be wrong.

Comment: i tried to reload the segments after the mov to cr0, but it bootlooped agin...

Comment: Ok, so even after doing long jump (by replacing `jmp main` with `jmp 0x08:main` or `ljmpl 0x08, main`, its still bootlooping before the C code or if not it still fricks up the resolution to that original issue 4000x720px)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to init the video mode in real mode, so the vga code inside protected mode wasnt needed. 
For anyone having same issue here is the code.

```
    mov ax, 0x4F02
    mov bx, 0x11B
    int 0x10

    or

    mov ah, 0
    mov al, 13h
    int 0x10
```

Modes: https://web.archive.org/web/20030603170438/http://www.vesa.org/vbelink.html

Comment: Btw if anyone knows how to switch between pages or banks in vesa, please tell me.